# Rename all files with a specific name in all folders and child folders of a given directory in cmd

Tags: command-line, powershell

I've got a prediciment where I've got about 300+ files that are supposed to be named ***notes.chart*** but are instead named ***notes (1).chart***

Many of these files are tucked in sub folders of sub folders:
*band-name/album-name/song-name/notes (1).chart*

I know the idea relatively well of what I need to do I just don't know how to do it PowerShell/Command Prompt and I don't know which to use to begin with. Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/245840/3395469

Answer (score 1):

Powershell, from the root directory of the sub folders.

```
gci -recurse "notes (1).chart" | ren -NewName "notes.chart"
```